# How can we subsample a pandas dataframe within every value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a dataframe with a column that gives clusters and I'd like to perform a kfold with the same fraction in train and test in every cluster.

I know I can do it myself with the following code:

```
nb_fold = 10
for i in range(nb_fold):

    X_train= X.groupby('Cluster').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac = 1/nb_fold))
    X_train.index = temp.index.droplevel(0)

    Y_train = Y.loc[X_train.index]

    X_eval, Y_eval = X.drop(X_train.index), Y.drop(Y_train.index)
```

But I wondered if there was a scikit learn wrapper for that since this does a draw with replacement and I could use a draw without replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need [`StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). It usually helps keep the distribution of classes the same across folds in classification tasks. But you can stratify on cluster labels to achieve the desired effect.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
for train_ind, eval_ind in skf.split(X, X['Cluster']):
    X_train, Y_train = X.iloc[train_ind, :], Y.iloc[train_ind]
    X_eval, Y_eval = X.iloc[eval_ind, :], Y.iloc[eval_ind]
```